# Why ExpandoObject doesn't work properly with Guid converted to string?

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression-trees

I have a piece of code that works properly if you pass two strings. For some reason it doesn't work the same if you pass GUID converted to string.

In more details, if I create a new ExpandoObject and pass string value it works but if I pass GUID converted to string it doesn't.

The code below should compare two parameters. In my example I pass the same two strings. With Equal operator it should return `true` if the strings are the same. If second parameter GUID converted to string it returns `false` even strings are the same. `dynamicObj.Add(memberName, Guid.Parse(value).ToString());`

Not sure what I'm missing. Here is my code.

```
 string value = "642188c7-8e10-e111-961b-0ee1388ccc3b";

 string memberName = "State";
 string contactValue = value;

 var dynamicObj = (IDictionary<string, object>)new ExpandoObject();   dynamicObj.Add(memberName, Guid.Parse(value).ToString());

 var expression = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object), "arg");
 var binder = Binder.GetMember(CSharpBinderFlags.None, memberName, null, new[] { CSharpArgumentInfo.Create(CSharpArgumentInfoFlags.None, null) });

 var property = Expression.Dynamic(binder, typeof(object), expression);

 var isValid = false;
 var right = Expression.Constant(contactValue);
 var result = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, property, right);
 var func = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(dynamicObj.GetType(), typeof(bool));
 var expr = Expression.Lambda(func, result, expression).Compile();

 isValid = (bool)expr.DynamicInvoke(dynamicObj);
```

Comment: do you get any exceptions?

Comment: I don't get any exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The GUID parsing will end up with the same string (value) as just using a string literal.

The difference however is the way it is stored in the dictionary: it's of type `Dictionary<string, object>`. This means that the `Object` class its `==` operator will be used which does a reference equality check. The `String` class, however, overloads this by doing a value equality check.

That's why this returns true:

```
Console.WriteLine(value == Guid.Parse(value).ToString());
```

While this returns false:

```
Console.WriteLine((object) value == (object) Guid.Parse(value).ToString());
```

Since strings are immutable, `Guid.Parse(value).ToString()` will create a new `string` object and do a reference equality check compared with `contactValue` (which is the same as `value`). This will evidently return `false` compared to using `value` all along which returns `true` because you never create a new object.

In order to make it work you can just cast the dynamic operand to a `string` so it will use the correct overload:

```
var castDyn = Expression.Convert(property, typeof(string));
var result = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, castDyn, right);
```

Comment: Thank you @Jeroen Vannevel. It works. Thank you for the explanation too.